# Can tensorflow lite model be zipped before adding it to Android app?

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow, memory-management, tensorflow-lite

My goal is to have a smaller tflite model. To that end, I thought of zipping the tflite model and adding it to Android app. From within the Android app, I can always unzip the model and use it.

I have already tried compressing a tflite model, and then uncompressing it. The uncompressed model works fine in the Python API. This kind of leads me to believe that it should work fine in the Android too.

However, I could not find any references at all of using a lossless compression (like zipping) for tflite models to reduce their size further online. So, I wanted to ask if anybody here has any clues on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a smaller TFLite file, you can always use [post-training quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization). Another method could be to host your model on [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models).

Comment: Shubham Panchal, I have already used post-training quantization. I wanted to see if I could reduce the size further

Comment: @PerracoLabs, I know APK is a zip file .. but the thing is tensorflow asks us to add tflite models in the {noCompress} tag.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Lite uses [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/), which provide a way for the runtime to 'read' the model off the original location without any parsing/serialization.

For this to work, the model must be present in memory as is, so I would say that it won't make sense to compress the model.